# Execute command once per true condition(s) & wait until condition(s) returns false then true again

Tags: bash, shell, loops, networking, conditional-statements

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092366/if-network-interface-switches-kill-process-and-restart) (which you might wanna check) and didn't receive an answer, so I'm going to try and simplify it a lil.

```
#/bin/sh

. /etc/ssh/autossh.conf

if [[ $(ifconfig pdp_ip0 |grep inet) && ! $(ifconfig en0 |grep inet) ]];
then
export NETTEST1=1; echo true
else
export NETTEST1=0; echo false
fi

if [[ ! $(ifconfig pdp_ip0 |grep inet) && $(ifconfig en0 |grep inet) ]];
then
export NETTEST2=1; echo true
else
export NETTEST2=0; echo false
fi

while
test $NETTEST1 -eq 1;
do
echo true
done

while
test $NETTEST2 -eq 1;
do
echo true
done
```

The problem with this bit of code is it will keep executing the command while the condition is true. I need it to only execute once per true statement then wait until the statement is false then true again. I've been beating my head in over it & I'm wondering if it's even possilbe. Any help is always appreciated.

Should I be doing like this:

```
    while true; do
    while ifconfig pdp_ip0 |grep inet && ! ifconfig en0 |grep inet;
    do sleep 1; done
    while ! ifconfig pdp_ip0 |grep inet && ifconfig en0 |grep inet; do sleep 1; done
    killall autossh; start-autossh
    done;
```

Comment: The `ifconfig` commands are executed once (and only once) in the `if` statements. Then the script will either exit (if NETTEST1 and NETTEST2 are both zero) or loop forever (if either NETTEST1 or NETTEST2 is 1).

Comment: Yes but it needs to continuously check the condition of the interfaces. Where echo true is on the while loop id put killall and the other script I'm executing. If I did it this way it would keep killing my script unnecessarily.

Comment: Tangential to the question (which I don't really understand): `if [[ ! $(ifconfig pdp_ip0 |grep inet) && $(ifconfig en0 |grep inet) ]];` is unnecessarily complicated (although it will work). You can more simply write: `if ! ifconfig pdp_ip0 | grep -q inet && ifconfig en0 | grep -q inet; then ...`

Comment: It really is a complicated problem that I am trying to solve. I need the checking script to kill a binary when one of the interfaces goes off then restart it. The problem is it's something that needs to be done once per true. That's why I need to wait for a false to get returned before executing on a true again. It has to do with my network interfaces getting turned off and autossh not knowing how to switch to the active interface.

Comment: @Geofferey: Does iOS have `/etc/network/if-up.d` and `/etc/network/if-down.d` scripts? That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @rici No it doesn't, I was actually looking into that. Maybe a loop within a loop on some inception ish lol. So first part of loop would look for the true then execute commands & continue to second part looking for false, when the false gets found it would return to beginning of loop.

Comment: @Geofferey: Yeah, that sounds about right. pseudocode: `while true; do while condition; do sleep 1; done; while ! condition; do sleep 1; done; execute_the_payload; done`. That assumes that the condition will not be false for less than a second, which is probably the case with network ups and downs.

Comment: @rici You think you could show me that in an answer? The net condition could be false for ever as long as I have both of the interfaces on or it could be true if I have even one off... The problem occurs when I switch the interfaces off/on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to trigger some command on an "edge transition"; that is, the transition of a condition from false to true. You could do it something like this (leaving out the details of what the condition and the action are):

```
while true; do
  while condition; do sleep 1; done
  while ! condition; do sleep 1; done
  do_what_needs_to_be_done
done;
```

Assuming that the condition (which can be any pipeline) never flips back and forth in less than a second (or that you don't mind missing the action in case that happens), this should do `do_what_needs_to_be_done` whenever `condition` changes from failure to success.

That caveat is one of the reasons why "edge transitions" are viewed with suspicion. While it seems likely that the one-second threshold is fine for a network up or down change, which generally takes several seconds at least, you also need to factor in the problem that your script might not be scheduled sufficiently often if the device is operating under load (or sleeping). But it will probably be better than nothing.

For clarity, I think the problem you have is slightly more complicated, so here's a slightly more articulated solution:

```
# Do this forever
while true; do
  # Figure out which interface is up (if any) at the beginning
  if ifconfig en0 | grep -q inet; then IF=en0
    elif ifconfig pdp_ip0 | grep -q inet; then IF=pdp_ip0
    else IF=
  fi

  # Some interface should be up at this point, but if not,
  # there is no point waiting for it to go down.  
  if [[ $IF ]]; then
    while ifconfig $IF | grep -q inet; do sleep 1; done
  fi;
  # Now whatever was up is down. Wait for something to come up.
  while ! ifconfig en0 | grep -q inet && ! ifconfig pdp_ip0 | grep -q inet; do
    sleep 1
  done

  # Some interface is up, so do the dirty deed
  killall autossh; start-autossh
  # And go back to waiting for the interface to drop.
done
```

Comment: can you check my main post and tell if if thats how I should do it?

Comment: You probably want `grep -q` rather than just `grep` since you don't want any output. But the other issue is that those two conditions are not inverses of each other: it is possible for both network interfaces to be down. I think what you probably want to do is `while true; do while the current network interface is up; do sleep 1; done; while neither interface is up; do sleep 1; done; do_what_needs_to_be_done; done`. The complication is knowing what the "current" network interface is; you'll want to have a shell variable whose value is either `en0` or `pdp_ip0` and set it accordingly.

Comment: I'm even more confused now. This is the most complicated thing I've done with bash in a while. The current net interface could be any one at any time :/ I have not even found a way to find out which one is the active one. If I could find out which one is active it'd make this way simpler. I could have it kill autossh when the active interface changes and start up again.

Comment: @Geofferey: there you go. It's not that complicated, honest.

Comment: Lol okay I'll try that and see what it does. I've never used elif btw... Just one more thing to pick your brain on... Do you know a way to check what interface is actually active?

Comment: @Geofferey: Sure: that's the code with an `elif` in it. It even has a comment stating what it does :) (`elif` is mostly just a contraction of `else if` except that it doesn't need a separate `fi`.)

Comment: Okay I see now :) but I can't find the error in your code.  /usr/bin/revssh-netwatch: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/usr/bin/revssh-netwatch: line 29: `done'

Comment: It was missing a do. fixed. sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry lol. I should be hahaha. I feel like I should know a lot of this... or been able to find that error on my own.

Comment: @Geofferey: you got me. What's line 20? I can't see how you've typed it.

Comment: I found out, an extra space got appended after grep on line 20. Now for the testing ;) to see how well it holds up. Thanks again man for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Something like this?

```sh
do_test_1() {
    {   ifconfig pdp_ip0 | grep -q inet; } &&
    { ! ifconfig en0     | grep -q inet; }
}

if do_test_1; then
    echo "true once"
    while ! do_test_1; do 
        sleep 60   # or some amount
    done
    echo "true once again"
fi
```

Comment: Did you check the link? It explains what I am trying to do and why. Yours looks like it will execute command and wait 60 seconds and execute again if the condition is still true. I need it to execute once on a true and wait for false then true again.  Thank you btw for your answer but I'm not sure if it will work.